# JavaFx Drag and Drop between 2 Swing JFXPanels not fully working?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, javafx

I have a Swing application, and inside my JFrame there are 2 JFXPanels, containing 2 JavaFx Nodes, a TableView and a WebView. The table contains a list of urls (think of it like a bookmarks list). I want the user to drag a url from the table on the left to the webview on the right. I set up drag-and-drop events according to the JavaFx tutorial and answers to previous drag-and-drop questions here. However, the 2 JFXPanels seem to not be able to communicate with each other.

I can drag URLs from the table to outside of my application (e.g. my web browser) and that works OK.

I can also drop URLs from the outside (e.g. copied from by web browser's address bar) to the web view and it loads them correctly too.

But when I drag URLs from the table, and try to drop them on the WebView, I always get an empty dragboard on the target side (I tried using both the String and the Url data formats, but both come back as null, also the event.getGestureSource() comes back as null), eventhough the source fills it correctly (watched it step-by-step with the debugger).

Could this be a side-effect of the fact that this is between 2 JFXPanels, and there is Swing in between which handles drag-and-drop using a different API? By the way, I do not have any other drag-and-drop code in the remaining Swing part of the application, so not mixing the two event models.

Thanks in advance for any pointers, tips or ideas.

Sample code snippets of my event handlers below:

(using JavaFx2.2, Jdk 1.7.0_40, on Windows 7 64 bit machine)

```
/* on the source side, the TableView */

// initiate drag
table.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    /* Put the selected file or url on the dragboard */
    MyObject tableItem = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            String item = tableItem.getUrlString();
    if (item != null)
    {
        Dragboard db = table.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(item);
        content.putUrl(item);
        db.setContent(content);
    }
    event.consume();
     }
});
table.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
    @Override 
    public void handle(DragEvent event) 
    {
    event.consume();
     }
});


/* on the target side, the WebView */
   webView.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    if (event.getGestureSource() != webView && (db.hasUrl() || db.hasString())) {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
    } else {
        event.consume();
    }
    }
});

// handle drop
webView.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    boolean success = false;
    String urlDropped = db.getUrl();
    if (urlDropped == null)
        urlDropped = db.getString();
    if (urlDropped != null)
    {
        webView.getEngine().load(urlDropped);
    }
    event.setDropCompleted(success);
    event.consume();
    }
});
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line. 3) What does this have to do with Swing?

Comment: _side-effect of the fact that this is between 2 JFXPanels, and there is Swing in between_ - easy way to find out is to add the tableView and the webView in the same fxPanel :-) Could well be a bug, the swing/fx interoperation has little devils hiding at dark places ... Seconding @AndrewThompson's suggestion: please show a SSCCE so we could easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your swift replies. @kleopatra, I also thought I'd try adding both in the same JFXPanel which could prove if this is a JavaFX/Swing interoperation bug. However, in the current setup of the rest of the application, this will not be a possible way out (at least for the moment, due to lack of time). I know that an SSCCE is the best way to describe a problem but I'm afraid due to lack of time I could not provide one yet. Will get back to this issue later on hopefully with a more concrete description of the issue.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson  As for the Swing tag, this issue is actually about JavaFx and Swing interoperability with what regards the drag-and-drop functionality, hence I thought it was suitable.

Comment: Update: Indeed, as @kleopatra suggested, testing by putting both javafx components within the same JFXPanel does not have this problem. So I guess Swing does some wrong dragboard handling when passing it from one JFXPanel to the next. Eventually our whole application will switch to JavaFx so this is not a showstopper, but still, quite an irritating glitch in the in-between mixed-mode time as we migrate our code from Swing module by module.